# What are the advantages of a series emitter follower circuit for power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I saw a power supply made of many series emitter follower circuits.

The input voltage is about maximum 480VAC.

[image]

I understand the circuit of single emitter follower power supply concept, but I don't know why many series emitter follower circuits are used.

- Can it be replaced by series resistor?
- What are the advantages of using it?

Comment: I think that's called cascoding an emitter follower, not a series of emitter followers. But either way, it's to handle the high voltage because you won't find a BJT that can handle 680V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can it be replaced by series resistor?*

Not easily because the lowest transistor will only have a voltage rating of maybe 200 or 300 volts and, if the load on it's emitter is open circuit, there will be very little collector current and, the series resistor will not drop much voltage AND, nearly the full supply voltage will be put on the lowest transistor's collector i.e. it will likely destroy it: -

[image]

<sub>I have chosen an MPSA42 transistor because it looks as old as the OP's diagram and it has a voltage rating of 300 volts.</sub>

If you can guarantee a minimum load of several mA then it's possible that a series resistor can be used to replace the top two emitter followers.

> *What are the advantages of using it?*

It means you can have zero load current at the output and share the main DC voltage between three cascoded transistors thus, all three survive if the voltage rating for each isn't the full DC voltage from the bridge.